# Kubernetes :Any notification or event can be received when the NetworkPolicy effectively applied?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/116608 led me to post the issue here.

#### Description

It was not clear that how application (application uses k8s api) can know the NetworkPolicy applied to pods effectively.
Is there any ways or best practice for this, to receive the event or notification that tells that NetworkPolicy applied to pods effectively?

We need to check if NetworkPolicy is applied and test the network communication with application pods. but there seems to be no way to get notified that NetworkPolicy is applied effectively to the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

One way to determine if NetworkPolicy is applied effectively to the cluster is to check the status of the NetworkPolicy resource using the Kubernetes API. You can use the `kubectl get networkpolicy <policy-name>` command to check the status of a specific NetworkPolicy resource.

But looking at your usecase , best will be to use Kubernetes API client libraries in your application code to query the status of the NetworkPolicy resource. You can periodically check the status of the NetworkPolicy resource and take appropriate action in case it is not applied effectively.

The Kubernetes documentation has a section on the Kubernetes API client libraries that includes examples of how to use the libraries to interact with Kubernetes resources. You can find the documentation for the [Python client library here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/#python)

In addition, the Kubernetes API reference documentation provides detailed information about the Kubernetes API resources and methods. You can find the reference [documentation here:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/)

You can go through this doc to understand and get started with some examples provided in this doc for go and python
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/

Another [blog post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/watch-react-kubernetes-objects-changes-part-2-luca-sepe?trk=pulse-article_more-articles_related-content-card) which can help